# Automatically append "-bar" to foo to resolve foo as foo-bar.baz.com?

Tags: domain-name-system

In Linux (Ubuntu 18.04 and RHEL) my `/etc/resolv.conf` says:

```sh
nameserver 192.168.0.1
search baz.com
```

And I get this:

```sh
getent hosts www
192.168.0.2 www.baz.com
```

But I'd like to do this:

```sh
getent hosts foo
```

And get this result:

```sh
192.168.0.3 foo-bar.baz.com
```

Where `-bar` was appended to `foo` prior to resolving `.baz.com`.

This approach fails however:

```sh
/etc/resolv.conf
search: -bar.baz.com

getent hosts foo
echo $? # returns 2
```

Is this possible? It seems that `search` only appends domain names, not partial matches. Is there a better approach?

Comment: No, it's not possible that way.  Domains go into search.  Change the - to a dot to make .bar.baz.com a subdomain and it will.  If what you have in search was treated literally, it would search dns for 'foo.-bar.baz.com'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, there is no way to append "Search-Suffixes" that would modify any part of the "hostname" you are looking for.

In your "failed approach", it's actually attempting to lookup "foo.-bar.baz.com"